# Beginner with iOS - SIGABRT when referring to a simple method in my app?

Tags: ios, methods, sigabrt

I'm just starting with iOS development, trying to call a method(function?) in my code. In my .h file I have:

```
- (void)changeColour;
```

in my .m file I have:

```
- (IBAction)leftSwipeDetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    [self changeColour];

}

- (void)changeColour
{
    colourCount++;

    switch (colourCount)
    {
        case 1:

            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 2:

            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;
    }
}
```

This prompts a SIGABRT abandonment when I run the program, where it didn't when I didn't try calling a method. Is there anything wrong with this?

Thanks.

Comment: What you've posted should be ok. How did you declare colourCount?

Comment: Post the crash log and error.

Comment: post the crashlog, backtrace (just type bt in the debugger window). Does it crash on load? or does it crash at the leftSwipeDetected method? or in the changeColour method?

Answer (score 0):

Ok any way Try this,

```
  @interface ViewController ()
  {
     int count;
  }

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeDetected:)];
      rec.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
      [self.aView addGestureRecognizer:rec];
      [rec release];
      count = 0;

   }

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

    - (void)dealloc {
            [_aView release];
            [super dealloc];
        }


    -(void)leftSwipeDetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {
            [self changeColor];
    }

    -(void)changeColor
    {
            count++;
            switch (count) {
                case 1:
                    {
                        self.aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                {
                    self.aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                    break;
                }
                default:
                break;
            }
        if(count == 2)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
    }
  @end
```

Comment: Thanks Shan, I'll give that a try tonight, and if it doesn't work I'll post the crashlog etc as requested. :)

Comment: I tried the above code, but couldn't get it to work - seemed to fall over because of ARC?

When the program crashes it highlights this in the AppDelegate:

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        }

Comment: because i did without ARC

Comment: Do this create new project without ACR option (do not select Automatic reference counting) and try